# parameter dropping when using C linkage in a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code in `main.cpp`

```
extern "C"
{
    void bar(int x, char* s);
}

int main()
{
    bar(5, "hello");
}
```

Notice that function `bar` is declared as taking two arguments. This is then compiled and linked to a static library `bar.cpp` that contains this code

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    void bar(int x)
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```

Notice function `bar` takes only one argument.

The executable compiles successfully and prints `5`

I have three questions:

1. Shouldn't there have been a compiler error indicating the mismatch in the number of parameters?
2. In the scenario above, since the string `hello` is not received by `bar`, when and how is it destroyed?
3. Is it completely valid to write and use code as above (knowing parameters will be dropped)? What exactly are the semantics behind parameter dropping?

Comment: 1.  no, c is very relaxed.  it doesn't encode the parameters into the symbols.  2.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx, c calling convention requires the caller to clean up the stack, so it is ok.  if the callee doesn't use it, the caller will clean up afterwards.  3.  the right way is to use default parameter values.

Comment: No, it's up to you to keep the headers in sync with the library. Although if you keep adding parameters it will likely crash eventually.

Comment: This is UB. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your specify VS, the question is more generally answered about C++, compilers, and execution platforms in general.

1.) You instructed the compiler to follow the C style calling convention for your platform to reference a symbol not defined in that compilation unit. The compiler then generates an object which tells the linker "call `_bar` here" (may be `bar` depending on your platform), which happily resolves to the compilation output of `bar.cpp`.  The older C++ calling conventions would result in mangled names like `barZ8intZP8char` or worse depending on your compiler, to ensure overloading worked properly.  However newer compilers are possibly smarter (magic!) and may understand additional metadata stored in the object file.

A bigger issue for multi-platform code is concerned with stack ordering.  On a few platforms parameters are stored in reverse order on the stack than their declaration, thus your code would then be provided with the address of the string instead of the integer value.  Fine for printing an integer, but would result in (hopefully) a segfault with the first parameter being a string and the second being an integer in the function declaration.

2.) This depends on the platform you are using.  For most platforms related to the IA32 systems (x86, AMD64, IA64, etc), the caller is responsible for managing the parameters on the stack.  Thus the stack frame containing the extra parameter is discarded in full when the call is complete.  There are optimization cases where this may trigger a discrete bug where a frame is reused because the compiler was misinformed regarding the call stack.

3.) For application programming I would consider this a bad practice as it may introduce very hard to diagnose bugs.  I'm sure some one has found an edge case to that statement regarding binary compatibility; however I would prefer the compiler to be aware of the parameters to avoid the optimization bugs referred to in #2.